# Excel Function - If string from column A is found in Column B Then

Tags: excel

Column A has a list (first and last names) of all users who have an O365 license. Column B has a list of everyone in the company. Column C is associated with Column B and has the job title of everyone in the company.

I want each row in A to check all of B to see if they match. If they match I want to take the corresponding row in column C and copy/paste it into the same row in blank column D

| A (O365 License | B (All Employees | C (Job Title). | D (JobTitle) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | Jarvis Cobblepott | . IT Guy |  |
| Nancy Johnson | John Smith | . Receptionist. |  |
| Kevin Gordon | Henry Kissinger | Marketing |  |

Comment: please mock up some fake names and expected output.

Comment: I created a mockup table. So for this, Receptionist should appear in the 2nd open row in Column D (because his name is in the second row of B). John Smith and Kevin Gordon aren't showing in column B, so nothing will appear in Column D for those rows. 

So if Column B contains an employee who also is in A, then move what is in C to D (because I want all O365 license holders to have D filled out correctly, and C and B are intertwined data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively maybe:

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,B$2:B$4,C$2:C$4,"",0)
```

Or:

```
=BYROW(A2:A4;LAMBDA(r,X.XLOOKUP(r,B2:B4,C2:C4,"",0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I went with xlookup, did just what I wanted it to. =XLOOKUP(C3,B$3:B$900,P$3:P$900,"",0) and filled it all the way down to the bottom of the spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

Use ISNUMBER(MATCH()) to see if it exists:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,A:A,0)),C2,"")
```

[image]